# Git: Run through a filter before commiting/pushing?

Tags: git, testing, coding-style

Is there a way to run the changed files through a filter before doing the commit? I wish to make sure the files follows the coding standards for the project.

I would also like to compile and run some test before the commit/push actually takes place, so I know everything in the repo actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-commit hooks. Read up on [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). The Git Book has an [example](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) of how to write a Ruby script to run RSpec tests, for instance.

You just save the executable as .git/hooks/pre-commit - using a hashbang to specify the language. It is just an ordinary shell script, although you can use any scripting language, so long as it returns 1 if there is a problem and 0 if there isn't.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. With this I can force the repo to be as the coding standards for the project should be. Thanks a bunch. Now all I have to do is write some scripts to do what I wish to do.

Answer (score 3):

For the filter part, I would recommend a [smudge/clear driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728), with the 'clear' script containing all the formatting or checking you need (executing on commit)

[image: filter driver]

You can declare this [git attribute filter driver](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) only for certain types of files, only for certain directories within your repo.