# Git checkout does not throw away my changes

Tags: git

I am using git 1.7.1 on Windows XP with cygwin.
The issue can be best illustrated by example:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   system/application/config/email.php
#       modified:   system/application/config/upload.php
#       modified:   system/application/views/frontend/business_subscription/start_subscription.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git checkout system/application/config/email.php

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   system/application/config/email.php
#       modified:   system/application/config/upload.php
#       modified:   system/application/views/frontend/business_subscription/start_subscription.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git diff -w
```

Git shows that there are some changes in the listed files but I cannot get rid of the changes- the file is still there.
It seems that it only happens to files where there are no changes other than whitespace (because git diff -w does not output anything.

I think this *might* be caused by git's crlf settings, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: From `git config --list`:
core.autocrlf=input
core.safecrlf=false

Comment: If you do `git add system/application/config/email.php` what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any checkout file which result in a content (in the "working directory", i.e. directly in your disk as a file) different from the index mean some kind of "automatic content transformation" just took place.

- either an autocrlf setting (which [I recommend to set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlftrue-in-git/2825829#2825829))
- or a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638772/git-run-through-a-filter-before-commiting-pushing/2638946#2638946) (with smudge/clean scripts)

Comment: It seems that the problem was indeed caused by core.autocrlf When I set it to false the changes did not appear there. I guess it's time to convert the whole repository and my development team to use consistent newline characters.

Comment: @fest: yes, that is the idea. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278