# What's the format of an Eclipse preferences export?

Tags: eclipse, preferences, sharing

An export of the Eclipse preferences looks a lot like a Properties file. Is this correct?

I'd like to share preferences with my team and for that, I need to filter the data (update/remove local paths, etc). Does anyone know any tools for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Preferences in Eclipse are implemented by `org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences`. The `save(IPath location)` method will convert the internal structure to a `Properties` instance using `convertToProperties()` and then write the result to disk.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Workspace Mechanic for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/):

> The Workspace Mechanic automates maintenance of your Eclipse environment by tweaking preferences, adding extension locations, and so on. You can use it to:
>
> - Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces
> - Save time setting up new workspaces
> - Create tasks that ensure your favorite new preferences are applied to all your current and future workspaces. (This is one of our favorite features!)

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, the tool doesn't work for me (no menus/icons are added to the UI after installation).

Comment: I have used it in a project with good result. Unfortunately, it uses workspace wide preferences, which isn't good in many circumstances where you work on multiple development projects - e.g. as a consultant... May be they fix this in a next version :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have project-specific preferences, they will be [stored in the `.settings` directory of you project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790241/what-files-does-eclipse-store-java-code-style-settings-to/3790284#3790284).
That means you can [add them directly in your VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377) and share them through version control.

There is no native tool for filter them, but if you are using a Git repo, you can add [filter drivers for making sure you ignore any path-specific changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638772/git-run-through-a-filter-before-commiting-pushing/2638946#2638946).

Comment: My question is specifically about "Export -> Preferences". We already version the .settings directory.